# How to fork transferred data to a script with socat?

Tags: ssl, man-in-the-middle, socat

I want to analyze the transferred data between a client and a server with *socat*. I’ve managed to set up *socat* as a man-in-the-middle with the following command:

```
socat -x -v OPENSSL-LISTEN:4443,reuseaddr,verify=0,cert=server.crt,key=server.key OPENSSL:server.example:443,verify=0
```

Although I can see the transferred data, I want to send it to a script to process it for a later analysis.

Does anyone know a solution so that I can send each transferred data packet to a script?

Answer (score 2):

I’ve found a [solution that allows to log the transferred data into files using *tee*](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/machine/penguin-lust/src/socat-1.7.1.2/EXAMPLES):

```
socat OPENSSL-LISTEN:4443,reuseaddr,verify=0,cert=server.crt,key=server.key,fork SYSTEM:'tee requests | socat - "OPENSSL:server.example:443,verify=0" | tee responses'
```

This is one step closer to what I’m looking for.